# Iterating over an array of objects to create a post-listing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, object

a newbie here

```
const posts=[{icon: 'heart',
              color: 'teal',
              category: 'Lifestyle',
              title: 'This is title of the news',
              img: 'https://bbb.com/img38.jpg',
              content: `Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo
              minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor.`,
              by: 'Jessica Clark',
              date: '26/08/2016',
  }, ...]
```

I have an array of these post objects and I want to create an actual post-listing out of it.

1. Where should the array go? Firstly I have put in constructor() method, but now I'm getting suggestions it should go into ngOnInit().
2. Should I use ng-repeat for that and if so, how should I access what's in the constructor()/ngOnInit()?

I was fiddling around with

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="post in this.posts">
    <img src="{{post.img}}" alt="First sample image">
    <h6 class="pb-1"><i class="{{post.icon}}"></i> {{post.category}}</h6>
    <h4 class="mb-4"><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></h4>
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    <p>by <a>{{post.title}}</strong></a>,{{post.date}}</p>
</div>
```

But it did not bring success around, obviously.

Comment: _ng-repeat_ is angularjs whereas _constructor()/ngOnInit()_ is angular. Which version of Angular/AngularJs do you use ?

Comment: Angular 4.3.6
Angular Cli 1.4.9

Comment: Use it like this `<div class="row" *ngFor="let post of posts"></div>`

Comment: So you should use `*ngFor="let post of posts"` instead of `ng-repeat="post in this.posts"`

Comment: All right, thanks for guidance! So now the post does not get rendered at all, I feel it's because `posts` gets `undefined` somewhere along the way. Where is the correct place for an array of objects?

Comment: Can you share the code of your component where posts is initialized ?

Comment: @Antikhippe like this?
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZwPT5rpiLsO12j4BVa5g?p=preview

Comment: You are still mixing angular and angularjs in your plunker. Angular is not well initialized so you have {{...}} in your page. Please, submit a working plunker.

Comment: Well, from my understanding of the topic Angular gets "ill-initialized", because these interpolations lead to `undefined`. Have a lot of it in the console, where I get for example "Cannot read property 'img' of undefined". This is why I'm asking about a place in a component where it's appropriate to the array. Also I'm not sure how to compile ts files on plunkr, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my code was flawed in several ways. Correcting them led me to desired results - let me include them here so others may have a reference.

1. The Array for Objects to be interpolated can be provided "as is" inside the component, and making them `public` makes them accessible - like this:

   public posts: Object[] = [
   {
     icon: 'fa fa-heart',
   ...},{...}];
2. `ng-repeat` was a terrible idea stemming out of my lack of expertise about what I'm  actually doing. Proper way was `*ngFor="let post in posts"`. Everything else was OK.

Thanks anyway